# Page shows empty while component has many elements to show on the screen

Tags: angular

We are trying to place content from the data object in the rows and columns. However, screen shows empty and on the console when we checked errors it said uncaught errors but we are confused to figure out which lines are exactly wrong and how can they be fixed. Type script part is ok. It seems all errors are in HTML part of the component. Here is the code:

```
<div class="container justify-content-center">
<div class="row row row-centered justify-content-center" *ngFor="let restaurant of restaurants; let i = index" *ngIf="i % 3 == 0">
      <div class="col-md-3 centered col-md-offset-1">
        <span>
        <img
          [src]="restaurant.imagePath"
          alt="{{ restaurant.name }}"
          class="img-responsive"
          style="max-height: 300px; width:100%;">
      </span>
          <h2>{{restaurant.name}} </h2>
          <h2>{{restaurant.category}} </h2>
          <p>{{restaurant.description}} </p>
         </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 centered col-md-offset-1">
        <span>
        <img *ngIf="restaurants[$index + 1].imagePath != null" [src]="restaurant[i +
              1].imagePath"
          class="img-responsive"
          style="max-height: 300px; width:100%;">
      </span>
          <h2 *ngIf="restaurants[$index + 1].name != null">{{restaurants[i +
              1].name}} </h2>
          <h2*ngIf="restaurants[$index + 1].category != null">{{restaurants[i +
              1].category}} </h2>
              <p *ngIf="restaurants[$index + 1].description != null">{{restaurants[i +
              1].description}} </p>

      </div>
         <div class="col-md-3 centered col-md-offset-1">
        <span>
        <img *ngIf="restaurants[$index + 2].imagePath != null" [src]="restaurant[i +
              2].imagePath"
          class="img-responsive"
          style="max-height: 300px; width:100%;">
      </span>
          <h2*ngIf="restaurants[$index + 2].name != null">{{restaurants[i +
              2].name}} </h2>
          <h2*ngIf="restaurants[$index + 2].category != null">{{restaurants[i +
              2].category}} </h2>
              <p *ngIf="restaurants[$index + 2].description != null">{{restaurants[i +
              2].description}} </p>
                       </div>
      </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

What is wrong? How can we fix these errors and make it show the component on the browser?

Comment: Please include the error in your question. Also try, if at all possible, to minimise the  html code to the bare minimum via the usual dichotomic process.

Comment: Unexpected closing tag "h2". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag. For more info see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags ("  <h2*ngIf="restaurants[$index + 1].category != null">{{restaurants[i +
              1].category}} [ERROR ->]</h2>
              <p *ngIf="restaurants[$index + 1].description != null">{{restaurants[i +
        "):

Comment: @LucaCappelletti here is the error message

Comment: Please, include it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML template you have used **ngFor** and **ngIf** on same element but as per [angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#one-per-element) you can use only **One structural directive per host element**

You can use below syntax as per [ngFor syntax](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#syntax)  and use **ngIf** on div which inside **ng-template**

```
<ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="items" let-i="index" [ngForTrackBy]="trackByFn">
  <div>...</div>
</ng-template>
```

For column base layout what you can do is create one component for your column and pass your restaurant data as input to it. Use this new component three times in your html as below :

```
// Component
public items = new Array(Math.round(this.restaurents.length/3));

//Template

<ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="items" let-i="index" [ngForTrackBy]="trackByFn">
  <my-col [data]="itmes[i*3]" ngIf="itmes[i*3]">...</my-col>
  <my-col [data]="itmes[i*3 + 1]" ngIf="itmes[i*3 + 1]">...</my-col>
  <my-col [data]="itmes[i*3 + 2]" ngIf="itmes[i*3 + 2]">...</my-col>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: So how can this logic be implemented as described in the above?

Comment: The problem is that ngfor is needed for rows since there are 3 columns in each row.

Comment: The project is based on bootstrap 4 I don't think this solution will work with it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work perfectly:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div *ngFor="let restaurant of restaurants; let i = index" >
    <div class="row row-centered justify-content-center" *ngIf="i % 3 === 0">
              <div class="col-md-3 centered">
           <img
          [src]="restaurants[i].imagePath"
          class="img-responsive"
          style="max-height: 300px; width:100%;"/>
          <h2>{{restaurants[i].name}} </h2>
          <h3>{{restaurants[i].category}} </h3>
          <p>{{restaurants[i].description}} </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 centered">
       <img
          [src]="restaurants[i + 1].imagePath"
          class="img-responsive"
          style="max-height: 300px; width:100%;"/>
          <h2>{{restaurants[i + 1].name}} </h2>
          <h3>{{restaurants[i + 1].category}} </h3>
          <p>{{restaurants[i + 1].description}} </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 centered">
       <img
          [src]="restaurants[i+2].imagePath"
          class="img-responsive"
          style="max-height: 300px; width:100%;"/>
          <h2>{{restaurants[i+2].name}} </h2>
          <h3>{{restaurants[i+2].category}} </h3>
          <p>{{restaurants[i+2].description}} </p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Finally, I got a solution. It works!!